# I want to upload the files into mysql database using jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

I want to upload the files into mysql database using jsp.When i use input type="file", jsp is not returning full path. i need full path to upload a file in mysql db.

```
<form id="translationFormID" method="post" action="saveTranslation">

<input type="file" name="attachCV" id="attachCVID" value="Attach CV">

<input type="submit" name="submit" />

</form>
```

This is my jsp page. i calling the servlet 'saveTranslation' using post method.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String attachCV=null;
    try{
        String attachCV=request.getParameter("attachCV");
        System.out.println("path= "+attachCV);
    }
    catch(Exception){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is my servlet code. here getting and printing attachCV parameter. when i print the attachCV, its showing something like 'c:\fakepath\sample.docx'

Comment: Go ahead. You have our permission. :-) Since you've posted no code at all that shows what you've tried, your question is most likely going to be closed. There isn't enough information here to be able to answer your question. Just using `input type="file"` doesn't tell your server where to store it, and saving the "full path" to the client's folder (which is what setting `input type` would have available) is meaningless on the server.

Comment: please give some suggestions.

Comment: Would be good if you didn't repost the same question again. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *i need full path to upload a file in mysql db.*

There's a major thinking mistake here.

Imagine that *I* am the client who want to upload the file and that *you* are the server who need to get the file's contents. I give you my full local disk file system path `c:\path\to\sample.docx` as the sole information, exactly as you requested. How would you as being the server ever get its *contents*? Do you have an open TCP/IP connection to my local hard disk file system? Really?

This isn't how uploading files works. This would only ever work if the server runs at *physically the same* machine as the client, so that you can just use `FileInputStream` with that path. This would thus only ever work in the local development environment, but definitely not in real world production where the server runs at a physically different machine than the client, separated by a HTTP connection.

You should instead be interested in the sole file *contents* which the client has sent to you along with the HTTP request body. In HTML terms, you can use `<input type="file">` for this in a `<form enctype="multipart/form-data">`. A more detailed answer with full code examples can be found here: [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824) It describes the modern Servlet 3.0 way using `request.getPart()` and the previously defacto standard Apache Commons FileUpload API.

Once you've implemented it the right way, you should ultimately end up with an `InputStream` representing the file contents which you obtained from the Servlet 3.0 `part.getInputStream()` or the Apache Commons FileUpload `item.getInputStream()`. You can then just use [`PreparedStatement#setBinaryStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setBinaryStream%28int,%20java.io.InputStream%29) the usual way to store it in the DB and [`ResultSet#getBinaryStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBinaryStream%28java.lang.String%29) to retrieve it from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, 
You need to add an attribute `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` to your form tag.
The follwoing code solves your problem.

```
<form id="translationFormID" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  
 action="saveTranslation">
    <input type="file" name="attachCV" id="attachCVID" value="Attach CV">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: How would this help read the file content in the servlet?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Multipart data handler like `MultipartRequest` to read the file content in your servlet. The path returned by the client will always be a local one to the client and you have no other way to read the file except the multipart way. You can search in SO itself to find other alternatives of multipart request handlers.